# Who is Enoch's mother? How is Enoch born?

Tags: genesis, cain, enoch

Adam and Eve had two children Cain and Abel. Cain killed Abel. 
There is no knowledge about a female companion for Cain(male) in the Bible. 
Genesis 4:17 Cain had a son Enoch.
Who is Enoch's mother? How is Enoch born?

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE! This question has been answered in various ways by various theologians and denominations. Are there any denominational perspectives you're particularly interested in? For some tips on asking questions here, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) And for a quick orientation to this site, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question indeed ! I made some researches on wol.jw.org, and came accross this reference : http://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/2010649

Here is the summary :

> Although this is often asked as a trick question by Bible skeptics,
>   the Bible does provide sufficient detail to give a satisfactory
>   answer.
>
> Genesis chapters 3 and 4 present the following information: (1) Eve
>   was “the mother of everyone living.” (2) Time elapsed between the
>   birth of Cain and his offering the sacrifice that was rejected by God.
>   (3) Following his banishment to become “a wanderer and a fugitive,”
>   Cain worried that ‘anyone finding him’ might try to kill him. (4) God
>   set up a sign to protect Cain, indicating that either his siblings or
>   other relatives might try to kill him. (5) “Afterward,” Cain had
>   intercourse with his wife in “the land of Fugitiveness.”—Genesis 3:20;
>   4:3, 12, 14-17.
>
> From the above, we can rightly conclude that Cain’s wife was a
>   descendant of Eve born on an unknown date. Genesis 5:4 acknowledges
>   that during his 930 years of life, Adam “became father to sons and
>   daughters.” Of course, the Bible does not specify that Cain’s wife was
>   Eve’s daughter. Indeed, the fact that she is mentioned after Cain’s
>   banishment indicates that enough time had passed that she could even
>   have been one of Adam and Eve’s granddaughters. Hence, The Amplified
>   Old Testament describes Cain’s wife simply as “one of Adam’s
>   offspring.”